# How to edit photos without importing them to my pc?

Tags: windows-7, photos, windows-photo-gallery

I have been using windows Photo Gallery for some time. Recently, when I tried to edit a photo within a removable drive(exactly, an SD Card), it asks me first to import them to the PC.
[image]
But, I do not want them to be imported to my PC because I already have those pictures in the PC.
Is there any way to edit the pictures stored in a removable drive using Windows Photo Galley without importing them to my pc?

Comment: What process is that window to exactly?  It isn't standard, so it likely is third-party, and it isn't `Window Photo Gallery` either.

Comment: Are you refering to the **Import Dialogue Box**?

Comment: Something like this would happen easily if the reader for your SD card was a camera or a phone or device that does not have the old Mass storage way of mounting the sd card direct.  Are you putting the SD card into a hardware reader ?  What device shows in the device manager when this is plugged in?   What SD card and reader are you using?  Is it in 3.0 or 2.0 ports, is it running 3.0 or 2.0 compatable in a 3.0 port?

Comment: @Psycogeek The same happens for a pendrive too!